# Mapbox Natural earth map disappears on zooms 0 & 1

Tags: leaflet, geojson, cartography, mapbox, cartocss

As the title says, I'm currently using mapbox to create a little atlas app the issue is whenever I zoom out to anything lower than zoom level 2, the map dissappears with the map background being the only thing visible. Here's the CCSS I'm using

```
Map {
  background-color: #F2F7F7  ;
}


#ne_10m_admin_0_countries  {
  polygon-fill: #E3E6E8 ;
  line-width: 1;
  line-color: #C2C6C6;
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: It would be worth sharing the link to your map so that people can see the problem and try out solutions. It would be hard to provide any assistance with just the provided data.

Comment: The map is hosted locally I'm afraid, but this issue occurs even in the mapbox studio, would it help if I gave the access token and map ID?

Comment: The ideal is to provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces your issue, so that people can directly see what is going on and try out solutions that they can submit to you. At least if you can provide a link with live issue, it would help understand your issue better.

Answer (score 3):

Vector tiles have different data at each zoom level. I'm guessing that the source vector tile dataset you're using in your style does not contain any data at zooms 0 and 1, which is why it can only be styled starting at zoom level 2 (where there's actually data to style).

Answer (score 0):

Are you rendering with EPSG:3857 (or 900913), and the Natural Earth dataset contains the South Pole at -90°?

This line (in WGS84) can not be displayed in EPSG:3857. Try to remove the line in the source dataset with a GIS software like QGIS before rendering.